# How to generate UDP packet

Tags: networking, tcpip, telnet, udp

I want to generate UDP packet to test a program,
something equivalent to using telnet to test TCP port (Can telnet generate UDP packet?)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One word: [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)

Netcat is the go-to tool for this sort of thing.

You can thrash whatever port you choose with UDP packets with something like:

```
nc -u host.example.com 53 < /dev/random
```

(53 is your port number)

Or you can send an actual file, or tell it to bind that port and listen as a service, or whatever you like.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to merely send one UDP packet with some specified data, as opposed to [Satanicpuppy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/124673/280618) which continuously sends random data, you can do:

```
echo "foo" | nc -w1 -u 111.22.333.4 20000
```

Comment: For some reason, it sends a few "X" packets before sending "foo". Using `/dev/udp` avoid this.

Answer (score 9):

This one is good if you are trying to work with large packets.  netcat uses 1024 bytes in UDP mode.

```
nping --udp -p 2090 111.22.333.4 --data-length 1550
```

UDP mode, to port 2090 at address, with a packet length of 1550 bytes.

This is from the nmap package, or is sometimes packaged as nping separately.

Further info is at https://nmap.org/book/nping-man-general-operation.html

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Bash, you can use its `/dev/udp` virtual filesystem, like this:

```
echo -n "hello" >/dev/udp/localhost/8000
```

Shamelessly re-used from [this answer to "How to send only one UDP packet with netcat?"](//stackoverflow.com/a/16568803)

Comment: /dev/udp doesn't exist on my Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.4.0-66-generic

Comment: @Alex It's not a real file. It's a trick of Bash. It won't show up with `ls` or any other program.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use UDP terminal programs. Most of them can also send/receive TCP also. For example Docklight scripting terminal has that possibility. 
And then you send data same way as you would send it to serial port..